# No module named django.core.management,error while installing django in vm

Tags: django, python-2.7, virtual-machine

When I try to run my server using:

```
./manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

After browsing for a solution, I learned that Django was not installed so I tried installing it on a VM.

I tried the following:

```
pip install django
yum install django
yum install python-django
```

I also tried running these commands with sudo -s and sudo -E.

I am getting the following when I use pip cmd:

```
Downloading/unpacking django
  Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
  Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement django
No distributions at all found for django
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Using Yum I get:

```
No package python-django available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: if you are using pip for installing django, just type 'pip freeze' and check whether django is listed or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Install a new version of Python. Pip has to be installed for the new
  version. CentOS 6.6 has default Python 2.6 and the default pip
  doesn't work properly.
- Install Django with new pip.
- Do not install the new version of Python globally as CentOS relies on
  Python 2.6 for yum.